# Flutter SQLFLITE openDatabase() 'version' parameter

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart

Can someone please explain what is the significance of 'version' parameter in openDatabase function of Sqlflite package (Flutter).

I have gone through the documentation([link](https://pub.dev/documentation/sqflite/latest/sqflite/openDatabase.html)) but couldn't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you created a database with these columns `name` and `age` and published your app.
now you want to add to the table the column `age`, if you add it in the `create table` query it will give an error cause the table already exists, if you use `create table if not exist` query it won't create the new column since the table also already exists

so how will the previous users get the new `age` column?

that's where the version comes to play.

you increment the version and add in the `onUpdate` function a query to alter the table and add the `age` column,

```
if (DatabaseClient.dbOldVersion < 2) {
  await db.execute("ALTER TABLE $tableName ADD COLUMN Age INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
}
```

this way when you publish an update to your app and the previous user updates it, the first time they open the app after the update the `onUpdate` would get called cause their version of the database is not the same as the version you specified in this update

Note, you need to update the create query too, in case a new user downloads the app after the new version